# Keep conditional formatting on a emailed flow (Power Automate)

Tags: html, sharepoint, power-automate

I'm having problems on finding a way to keep the same conditional formatting I've configured on a Sharepoint list, when sending this list via a Power Automate email flow.

I've tried it with and without a Compose task including a CSS before the e-mail task. My list has a conditional formatting which indicates the late tasks in red

[image]

But on the email that red formatting is "forgotten".

[image]

Is there any way to make it appear on the e-mail too?

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible to apply similar styling to the Create HTML table outputs as well. Like you already mentioned, you can inject this CSS.

You can also make that conditional by using expressions. You could use an [if](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#if) and [less](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#less) functions to compare your TerminoReal column with [utcNow](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#utcNow).

```
if(less(item('TerminoReal'), utcNow()), '#FF0000', '#000000')
```

For the CSS injection itself I would suggest to have a look for example these blogs:
https://ryanmaclean365.com/2020/01/29/power-automate-html-table-styling/
https://tomriha.com/add-value-based-colours-to-html-table-created-in-power-automate/